# SortedList does not contain a definition for 'Item' error

Tags: c#

Trying to use the Item[Object] Property of SortedList Class to get the asscoiated value out the SortedList in a Win Form Application.

But it gives Error  1   '**System.Collections.SortedList' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.SortedList**' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Item Property is also not appearing in Intellisense

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SortedList myList = new SortedList();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string wordLine; 
            string[] strArray; 
            char sep = ' ';
            WordData myWord;

            StreamReader myWordFile = new StreamReader("OOP.txt");

            while (!myWordFile.EndOfStream)
            { 
                wordLine = myWordFile.ReadLine();
                strArray = wordLine.Split(sep);

                for(int i=0; i<strArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    string word = strArray[i];

                    if (myList.ContainsKey(word))
                    {
                        myWord = myList.Item[word];

                    }
                }



        }
            MessageBox.Show("File Read Successfull");

    }
    }
```

Comment: It should be `myWord = myList[word];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Item` property on collections in general are treated specially in C#. It is treated as the indexer in C# and is accessed through a normal index.

i.e.,

```
myWord = myList[word];
```

You cannot directly access the indexer property by name, the name is there for languages that do not directly support indexers.  Just be aware that it can be under a different name but the C# compiler uses `Item` by default.